# What should be the answer of this question?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, templates, definition

***Note:*** I got this question from a friend of mine. It was given to him in an interview exam. I'd done programming in C++ in my early days of university. Even though the question looked easy on the first glance, I couldn't find a good answer to it. That's why I'm asking here.

Given this C++ code below, please answer to the following 3 questions:

- What is the class supposed to do?
- There’s a major problem in the implementation of the class. Can you name it?
- Can you give 3 different ways of fixing this problem (Depending on the requirement specifications of that class)?

```
    template<typename T>
    class Array
    {
     public:
        Array(unsigned arraySize):
            data(0), size(arraySize)
        {
            if(size > 0)
                data = new T[size];
        }
        ~Array()
        {
            if(data) delete[] data;
        }

        void setValue(unsigned index, const T& value)
        {
            if(index < size)
                data[index] = value;
        }

        T getValue(unsigned index) const
        {
            if(index < size)
                return data[index];
            else
                return T();
        }

     private:
        T* data;
        unsigned size;
    };
```

Comment: (1) it encapsulates an array of values, (2) the copy semantics are broken (3) use a `std::vector`, use a `std::vector`, use a `std::vector` are the 3 fixes.

Comment: 2. Copy semantics are broken - means there is no mechanism to copy the encapsulated array?
3. I thought of that before, but could there be other concrete answer?

Comment: It means that rule of 3/5/0 is violated - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: *"There’s a major problem in the implementation of the class."* **A** major problem? If you tried to innumerate all of the problems this `Array` class has, you'd be at it all day. I also wouldn't know how to answer that question. How could I guess, among all of the problems present, which one the asker is asking about.

Comment: In addition to the major problems already pointed out, there are a few other minor stylistic issues as well: `data` should be initialized with `nullptr` rather than `0`. `size` is a bad name to use if someone adds `using namespace std;` at some point it clashes with `std::size`. The `if (data)` part of `if(data) delete[] data;` is pointless - `delete[] nullptr;` is valid and harmless. But really, just use a `std::vector` already.

Comment: François Andrieux, the constructor takes the size of the array. That means, you can loop through it. So, there should be no problem to innumerate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This class encapsulates an array of any kind of values. Similar to `RAII` [[See Here}](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii)
2. There is no copy semantics.
3. Ways to fix this problem

   - Use `std::vector`
   - Implement "The rule of three"/"The rule of five"/"The rule of zero" [[See Here]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)
   - Enable changing the size of the array after constructing it.
   - Initialize with `nullptr`
   - Instead of integer, use `std::size` or `size_t`
   - Change the name of the variable `size` which might conflict with `std::size` when `using namespace std` is used.
   - Replace `if(data) delete[] data;` with `delete[] data;` when `nullptr` is used to initialized the values.
   - Implement throwing of `std::out_of_range` in `getValue` and `setValue`

Answered by: [Bethsheba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2380830/bathsheba), [Slava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/432358/slava), [Jesper Juhl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5910058/jesper-juhl), [Vlad from Moscow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2877241/vlad-from-moscow)
, [eerorika](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2079303/eerorika)

Answer (score 1):

> What is the class supposed to do?

This is a question that cannot be conclusively determined by reading a program. Only the author knows for certain what they intended. Without documentation, at most we can make a guess.

My guess: It is an attempt at encapsulating the allocation of a dynamic array in a RAII container. A limited and buggy version of `std::vector`.

> There’s a major problem in the implementation of the class. Can you name it?

Here are several problems; some more major than others. Following are roughly in order of major problems first, minor problems last:

- The class is copyable and movable, but copying and moving results in undefined behaviour.
- There is no simple way of knowing whether `getValue` returns a value initialised object because that's the value at the index, or because the index is outside of bounds.
- It is unusable with move-only elements.
- It is unusable with non-default-constructible elements.
- It provides no iterators, so it cannot be used with standard algorithms.
- `if(data)` in destructor is redundant.

> Can you give 3 different ways of fixing this problem (Depending on the requirement specifications of that class)?

I'm assuming that the first issue I mentioned is the one that they refer to.

- Delete copy/move assignment/constructor. (Not necessarily ideal, since copying and moving are probably useful operations).
- Or implement them in a way that doesn't result in undefined behaviour. In particular, there must be a class-invariant that a single instance has unique ownership of the pointed array.
- Or use `std::vector` instead. This fixes all of the minor problems as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would want to append the answer of **@Arshad**.

For starters the size of the array should have the type `size_t`.

The member functions `setValue` and `getValue` should throw the exception `std::out_of_range`.

The function `getValue` should be overloaded for `const` and `non-const` objects and correcpondingly return either `const` or `non-const reference` to an element of the array.

It would be better to declare (also) the `operator []`.

It is desirable to initialize the array

```
data = new T[size] {};
```

Also the class shall have a member function named `size()` that returns the number of elements in the array. Otherwise the user of the class will not be able to specify correctly an index.

And I think iterators for the class also should be mentioned.:) Otherwise the class is not very useful and can not be used with standard algorithms as for example `std::fill`.:)